# How to retrieve & print values from array using Twig?

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig

I'm having trouble getting my values from my array to print out in a twig file.

Right now I have this:

```
ProductController.php on line 290:
array:1 [▼
  1 => array:3 [▼
    0 => "Water"
    1 => 5
    2 => 2.75
  ]
]
```

In twig I have this:

```
        <tbody>
            {% for cartValue in cartArray %}
                <tr>
                    <!--ERRORS BELOW NOW-->
                    <td>{{ cartValue }}</td>
                    <td>{{ quantity }}</td>
                    <td>${{ price }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}    
        </tbody>
    </table> <!--top table-->
```

In productEntity I have this:

```
    $cartArray = array();

    if (is_null($cartArray) || !$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Error: Nothin in Array/Entity');
    } else {
        $cartArray = $session->get('cartArray', []);
        // $cartArray[$entity->getId()] = $entity->getName();
        $cartArray[$entity->getId()] = [$entity->getName(), $entity->getQuantity(), $entity->getPrice()];

        foreach ($cartArray as $key => $product) {
                //dump($cartArray); die;
                //dump($key); die;
                $productEntity = $em->getRepository('PaTShopTestBundle:Product')->find($key);
                $quantity = $productEntity->getQuantity();
                $price = $productEntity->getPrice();
                $totalCostOfAllProducts += $price * $quantity;
        }
    }

    $session->set('cartArray', $cartArray); //session---------------

    //var_dump($cartArray); die;

    return array(
        'price'     => $price,
        'quantity'  => $quantity,
        'totalCostOfAllProducts'   => $totalCostOfAllProducts,
        'cartArray'   => $cartArray,
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
```

I want to be able to show the cartValue(name of product) quantity and price of each product in my array. If I add a second item to array I get this:

```
array:2 [▼
  1 => array:3 [▼
    0 => "Water"
    1 => 5
    2 => 2.75
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    0 => "Duck"
    1 => 3
    2 => 6.25
  ]
]
```

I keep getting some errors, this one being :

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion") in src/PaT/ShopTestBundle/Resources/views/Product/cart.html.twig at line 21.

I've tried referencing the index's of the array

In twig:

```
{{ cartValue[0] }}
{{ quantity[1] }}
```

but it stops working once quantity[1] is called: Error:

> Impossible to access a key ("1") on a integer variable ("3") in src/PaT/ShopTestBundle/Resources/views/Product/cart.html.twig at line 22

I know there is a way to do what I'm trying to accomplish but I just don't know it. I'm a newbie but I'm learning.

Any Help is truly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array loop in Twig is not proper..

If you do not want to use keys do this..

**EDIT: INDEXED ARRAY**

```
<tbody>
    {% for key, cartValue in cartArray %}
        <tr>
            <!--ERRORS BELOW NOW-->
            <td>{{cartValue[0]}}</td>
            <td>{{cartValue[1]}}</td>
            <td>{{cartValue[2]}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}    
</tbody>
```

**With keys..**
Modify your cartArray in PHP to look like this

```
      $cartArray[$entity->getId()] = [
        'name' => $entity->getName(),
        'quantity' => $entity->getQuantity(),
        'price' => $entity->getPrice()
      ];
```

Then in your Twig file do this,

```
        <tbody>
        {% for cartValue in cartArray %}
            <tr>
                <!--ERRORS BELOW NOW-->
                <td>{{ cartValue.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ cartValue.quantity }}</td>
                <td>${{ cartValue.price }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}    
    </tbody>
</table> <!--top table-->
```

Comment: I see that now, thank you. I do however get Error:  Key "name" for array with keys "0, 1, 2" does not exist in src/PaT/ShopTestBundle/Resources/views/Product/cart.html.twig at line 21. Any quick ideas as to why?

Comment: did you add keys(name, quantity, price) to your $cartArray  ?

Comment: I did      $cartArray[$entity->getId()] = [
                'name' => $entity->getName(), 
                'quantity' => $entity->getQuantity(), 
                'price' => $entity->getPrice()
            ];

Comment: I have made some edits, try passing key explicitly in the twig loop and revert your changes in $cartArray(as it was earlier - indexed)

Comment: I got it with your edit. Just added key to my twig for loop. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
    {% for cartValue in cartArray %}
        <tr>
            <!--ERRORS BELOW NOW-->
            <td>{{ cartArray[0] }}</td>
            <td>{{ cartArray[1] }}</td>
            <td>${{ cartArray[2] }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}    
</tbody>
```

or

```
$cartArray[$entity->getId()] = array('name' =>$entity->getName(), 'quantity' => $entity->getQuantity(), 'price' => $entity->getPrice());
```